# Saxon-HE 9.x, 11.x, 12.x - Indentation differences (depending on operating system (Debian vs. Ubuntu vs. RedHat) - unconfirmed)

Tags: java, xslt, operating-system, indentation, saxon

Here's an interesting observation. Indentation of XSLT transformation is different by operating system. Same Java code and XSLT template and Saxon-HE 11.2:

Ubuntu 22.04:

```xml
<isee:ISEE-Event xmlns:ex="http://www.example.com/schemas/ex/5.00"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 schemaVersion="5.00">
```

Debian 10 and RedHat

```xml
<isee:ISEE-Event xmlns:ex="http://www.example.com/schemas/ex/5.00"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  schemaVersion="5.00">
```

notice the extra space for the indented 2nd and 3rd line.

I understand that indentation is not strictly specified.
Does anyone have an explanation why this was implemented this way, specifically why it was changed?

Saxon-HE 9.x did not exhibit this behaviour.

Saxon-HE 12.2 consistently adds the extra space, regardless of operating system.

Here's some simple code and example input:

XSLT template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ex:root xmlns:ex="example">
   <ex:Property name="property-main-1"
                value="A pretty long value for an attribute. But we need to test the indentation as well"/>
   <ex:Property name="property-sub1-1" value="I'm the property from sub1.xml"/>
   <ex:Property name="property-sub2-1" value="I'm the property from sub2.xml"/>
</ex:root>
```

Comment: Consider to add minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code and details about as to how you run the transformation, so that anyone can easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see the extra space before the attributes on the second and third line with 11.5 and 12.2 but not 10.9 HE Java, all running from the command line, but I see it the same results under Windows and Ubuntu (22.04 WSL). Let's wait and see what Michael Kay thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, and not easy to explain! I'm seeing the extra space on my Mac too. I think I've noticed the effect before but was too busy to investigate it at the time.

The code did change in Saxon 10.x. Previously the attributes were passed to the XMLEmitter one at a time; from 10.x they are passed in bulk in the startElement event, which means we are able to assess the total length of all attributes, and either indent all of them or none, whereas previously the decision was made on-the-fly after previous attributes had overflowed the line length.

The code says

```
int indent = (level - 1) * getIndentation() + 3;
emitter.setIndentForNextAttribute(indent);
```

and if we change the "3" to "2", then the problem goes away.

I suspect the history is that in the past, we wrote the first N characters of a standard indentation string to the output writer: this will have included a newline, plus N-1 spaces. We now use a UTF-8 writer that has a primitive method to write N spaces (this saves the cost of testing each one to see if how many UTF-8 bytes to use), and we are passing the total number of whitespace characters, not the number of spaces.

I find it hard to believe there is a difference between operating systems here. I suspect it's almost certainly a difference between Saxon versions.

Bug raised at https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6063

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. We've compiled the Java code with Coretto 8, using Saxon-HE 11.2. Then created a docker image and ran it on various operating systems.

Comment: Re: OS differences - it must have been a fluke and I'm not going to investigate this further. Thanks again for picking this up and working it as a bug!

How long before an update version hits the streets?

Comment: Saxon-HE 12.3 indents "nicely" again - thanks!